# Addresses database schema for multiple entities

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm playing around with entity framework and code first approach. The scenario is this:

- An user can have multiple companies (each company has an address)
- An user can have multiple houses per company (each house has an address)

I'm thinking of two ways I can manage addresses:

- Have an `Address` table with a column for `CompanyId` and `HouseId` (for companies addresses only `CompanyId` will be inserted and for houses both Ids will be inserted.
- Have a `CompanyAddress` and `HouseAddress` tables with the only difference between them being the FK for `CompanyId` versus `HouseId`.

How would you do it? Is there any other, better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core you should use [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) for this.  In EF 6, use a [Complex Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#specifying-that-a-class-is-a-complex-type).  Both allow you to have an Address type in .NET without having an Address table in your database.

Comment: David if you have the time, please look at [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104976/one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships-with-same-owned-entity-type) following your answer.